# Unable to create volume

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I am trying to mount a local directory on the Windows host within a Linux container.

To do this I am creating a volume using the command :

```
docker volume create --driver local --name filesystemshare --opt type=bind --opt source=//D/Code/docker/xxxx/filesystemconnector/data --opt target=/fileshare
```

However, I am getting the following error.

```
Error response from daemon: create filesystemshare: invalid option: "source"
```

How can I correctly create and attach a new volume to my Windows host within a Linux container using Docker?

Comment: As described on this page (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/), the built-in local driver on Windows does not support any options.

Comment: So how can I achieve what I am doing in Windows?

Comment: Use a bind volume instead https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/. This is an option added to the `docker-compose.yml` file or the `docker run` command.

Comment: But if I had a new file to the host location I have to rebuild the container, which is not idea.

Comment: Volumes are not actually part of the container itself. A bind volume is more like sharing a folder, in that changes to the host are seen in the container and vice versa.

Comment: Why don't you create through docker-compose